# Java, low memory warning only after GC

Tags: java, memory-management, out-of-memory

I've installed a low memory detector within my Java application, and it seems to work well. I'm using `MemoryPoolMXBean` in combination with a `NotificationListener`, setting the `collectionUsageThreshold` for the heap to `size * 0.9999`

However, I've also got a lot of SoftReferences in my application. Even if the application runs just fine without my low memory detector the detector throws warnings - most probably because the SoftReferences have not been cleared out by the GC yet.

Is there any way to warn me if x % of the available memory are used up AFTER ALL SoftReferences that can be cleared have been cleared?

Comment: Log output: "89307560 of 89522176 B are already in use." when I output: tenuredHeap.getCollectionUsage().getUsed() and tenuredHeap.getUsage().getMax() ... however, If I just go on, no OOM is thrown...

Shortly after I can see SoftRef-Unload-Log-Output from my background-remove-from-reference-queue-reader-Thread.

Comment: How does your scheme know when you have "low memory"?  What is the definition?

Comment: As I said in my original post:
`tenuredHeap.setCollectionUsageThreshold(memoryThresholdInBytes);`

Comment: This level of memory monitoring is unlikely to be useful.  I would make sure you have a machine with plenty of memory.  You can buy 64 GB for less than £300, and let the JVM manage the memory for you rather than trying to micro-manage the memory manager.

Comment: But as you mention, soft references are only cleared if memory is REALLY tight (or if you clear them), and if you're using soft references a lot then you could have an apparent "low memory" scenario when there is no real problem.

Comment: Please do not go off-topic. I know that memory is cheap, but that is not the case in some small environments. I'm not trying to manage the JVM with SoftReferences either. I've got data that is too big for my environment but on the other hand I have to fulfill certain interfaces. To fulfill them I'm loading the data on-demand fropm a file => however, for performance reasons I put everything into SoftReferecnes to hold the data as long as possible instead of building my own cache => SO THE JVM CAN DO THE MANAGING.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Java implementation of soft references is at best flaky, and, when heavily used, is apt to lead to scenarios like yours.  You could, in theory at least, use your "low memory" signal to cause you to clear soft references on an LRU basis.  (Whereas Java will clear them arbitrarily.)

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your answer, however, this means there is no good way to detect a "real" low-memory situation. That's bad :/